# How to write in a temp directory in Lambda in the same invocation?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless

I just need to download an image file, validate its format for now, may be resize it later, then pass it to another library to work with it, all in one invocation. Is there any way I can use a temporary directory in Lambda function? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a file to the temp directory /tmp directory storage in lambda. It has a limit of 512 MB. Below is an example

```
var fs = require("fs");

 exports.handler = function(event, context) {
   fs.writeFile("/tmp/test.txt", "testing", function (err) {
    if (err) {
        context.fail("writeFile failed: " + err);
    } else {
        context.succeed("writeFile succeeded");
    }
  });
 };
```

Comment: Oh! Splitting my function into two? This is so much. There must be a better way.

Comment: Update: AWS lambda now supports the `/tmp` directory storage up to 10Gig. So, you can increase the `/tmp` directory based on your requirements.